# Split apk crashes with null , without splitting works fine

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Here is my app level gradle -

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    ---------
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi","armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a","mips","x86","x86_64"
        universalApk false
    }
}
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi':3, 'armeabi-v7a':4, 'arm64-v8a':5, 'mips':6, 'x86':7, 'x86_64':8]
import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def baseAbiVersionCode =
            project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))
    if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
    }
}
```

I am getting the split apk's but on running them app is crashed with error -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                   at -----------.SplashActivity$5.a(Unknown Source)
```

I am unable to pin-point the issue.On running the universal build everything works fine. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: past your `SplashActivity` code

Comment: share SplashActivity .java error is in there

Comment: i was able to pin point it to rest-client handler , by removing api request it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to working by setting

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Earlier it looked like this -

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        useProguard true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I am not sure why using progaurd caused issue.